# What is the main difference between C++ vs C++.NET?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
>   [What is the difference between Managed C++ and C++/CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443811/what-is-the-difference-between-managed-c-and-c-cli) 
>   [What is CLI/C++ exactly? How does it differ to 'normal' c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399493/what-is-cli-c-exactly-how-does-it-differ-to-normal-c)

I am in doubt of distinguishing between C++ and C++.NET.

Is that right C++ is unmanaged code and C++.NET is managed code?

I need to program for a project in C++. For better building the GUI, I would prefer to use C++.NET.

I also have another plain C++ library (unmanaged C++ DLL file), will it be possible to use it as a normal DLL library in the C++.NET project?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

> Is that right C++ is unmanaged code and C++.NET is managed code.

There's no such thing as "C++.NET". There's C++/CLI, which is basically C++ with Microsoft extensions that allow you to write code targeting the .NET framework. C++/CLI code compiles to CLR bytecode, and runs on a virtual machine just like C#. I'll assume you're actually talking about C++/CLI.

With respect to that, one can say standard C++ is unmanaged and C++/CLI is managed, but that's very much Microsoft terminology. You'll never see the term "unmanaged" used this way when talking about standard C++ unless in comparison with C++/CLI.

Both standard C++ and C++/CLI can be compiled by the same Visual C++ compiler. The former is the default on VC++ compilers, while a compiler switch is needed to make it compile in latter mode.

> I need to program for a project in C++. For better building the GUI, I
>   would prefer to use C++.NET.

You can build GUI programs in C++ just as well as C++/CLI. It's just harder because there isn't a standard library in standard C++ for building GUI like the .NET framework has, but there are lots of projects out there like [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products/) and [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/) which provide a C++ GUI framework.

> I also have another plain C++ library (unmanaged C++ dll), will it be
>   possible to use it as a normal dll library in the C++.NET project?

Yes. It might take some extra work to deal with the different standard C++ data types and .NET data types, but you can certainly make it work.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. If so, should I use C++/CLI in Visual Studio to build the GUI instead of using QT or wxWidgets? because using QT or wxWidgets, I introduce another dependency of my application. I suppose that if I just use C++/CLI managed, I only need to have .net framework. What is the pros and cons of using C++/CLI, QT and wxWidgets? could you please help me to clarify about them? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @devn: The .NET framework is also a dependency that's even bigger than either Qt or wxWidgets, so you're going to need a dependency in any case. Note that Qt and wxWidgets do not require a .NET framework to work.

Comment: using wxWidgest or QT can make your application portable across multiple platforms. .NET guarantees that you are fixed on VisualStudio / Windows. If you are already familiar with the .NET Framework it reduces the effort compared to working with a completely new framework. On the other hand, using pure C++ libs does not introduce an additional layer (ref classes vs. native classes) that you have to master. In short - it depends on your knowledge and use case.

Comment: @In silico: no it is not necessarily. If you plan to deploy only on windows and if you always want to use Visual Studio, .NET Framework is not a big concern. It is available on most computers anyway where QT/WX isn't.

Comment: @Tobias Langner: There isn't a Qt or wxWidgets "runtime" you need to install on client machines to run Qt or wxWidgets applications. AFAIK they can be compiled statically and these frameworks depend only on operating system primitives. If not statically you only need to ship a DLL along with the application.

Comment: OK. It is more clear but requiring .net framework is fine with my application. the thing is that I am very familiar with C# therefore It is more convenient with me to create a C++ Windows Form project in Visual Studio. You said it is possible to add the C++ dll library in the C++.NEt project but when I try to add a reference, I got an error: the dll is nether a .NET assembly or a registered ActiveX control. Do I have to use a pinvoke way to create a wrapper to call the methods?

Comment: .Net Framework is very much stable and can be able to meet your needs. If you don't want to use .Net Framework you can use MFC which is also referred as VC++ sometimes.

Comment: @Atique: MFC has never been reffered to as VC++ ever in the history of its existence. It has always been something separate from VC++. They are sometimes used together, but a person calling MFC as VC++ is simply wrong.

Comment: @TobiasLangner, yes, my target is only windows and using Visual Studio. So I think .NET framework is a good choice for me. The current problem is that I am facing a problem to call the methods of a native C++ dll in the C++.NET project. Do you know a sample available somewhere? or I have to use the pinvoke way to create a wrapper as juergen mentioned below? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Insilico: I have seen the usage many times. For example, [http://www.functionx.com/visualc/](this).

Comment: @Atique: I don't see how that's an example. On that page it says "Visual C++/MFC" to refer to the fact that the articles on the page talk about both Visual C++ and MFC. I don't see anywhere that says that MFC == VC++.

Comment: *"C++/CLI code compiles to CLR bytecode, and runs on a virtual machine just like C#."* - That's inaccurate. C++/CLI can produce mixed mode assemblies, that contain both native machine code, as well as IL. Neither C++ nor C# compile to bytecode, and neither run in a virtual machine (the CLR is a virtual execution environment).

Answer (score 13):

Managed C++ is a now **deprecated** Microsoft set of deviations from C++, including grammatical and syntactic extensions, keywords and attributes, to bring the C++ syntax and language to the .NET Framework. These extensions allowed C++ code to be targeted to the Common Language Runtime (CLR) in the form of managed code as well as continue to interoperate with native code. Managed C++ was not a complete standalone, or full-fledged programming language.

Managed C++

```
#using <mscorlib.dll>
using namespace System;

int main()  {
  Console::WriteLine("Hello, world!");
  return 0;
}
```

Vanilla C++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  cout << "Hello, world!";
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Completely useless "information". The question is clearly asking about C++/CLI which isn't deprecated.

Answer (score 9):

Well... C++ .NET is kind of a misnomer. 
You can program in C++ using visual studio .NET. Well that's what it was called along time ago. Now a days folks just call it Visual Studio, with the dot NET moniker. Well, at least the splash screen doesn't have a big ol .NET in the logo anymore.

It is kind of understood that using Visual Studio (VS), you can program in managed and unmanaged languages (Lots of choices there btw).

If you want to program in C++ using Visual Studio you have two choices:

1. Unmanaged or native C/C++. This is the old (or new I guess too) C++
   that you have always known, and you program with unmanaged memory.
2. Managed C++. They call this C++/CLI. That is read C++ over CLI, not
   C++ divided by CLI! This is C++ that has extra keywords, and a few
   extra syntax elements than the native C++. This allows you to
   utilize the .NET Foundation Class Library and do other fun things in
   the .NET framework. This of course uses the garbage collector for
   memory for managed types.

Personally my favorite language is C#, but if you need to interop between C++ and .NET than definitely use Managed C++. It is very easy to do, and I think is easier than that other P/Invoke stuff.

If you are going to some project, I would suggest you do your UI in C# and take advantage of all that it has to offer. Then have that reference a mixed mode managed library that contains your C++ code. I think that will be a lot easier for you.

The answer to your last question is yes, you can definitely use that in your app.

Here is how the dependencies would work:

[C# App/GUI] depends on [Managed C++ assembly] depends on [Native C++ Lib]

Comment: Just an addendum- Managed C++ is now considered deprecated in favour of C++/CLI (source: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/managed-c%2B%2B/info).

Comment: Let's combine both. C# UI and C++ skeleton.

Answer (score 3):

- Yes, C++ is unmanaged code and C++/CLI is managed.
- Yes, you can use your unmanaged C++ DLL in your C++/CLI project. But you have to write a wrapper for that. That means you have to define the unmanaged methods you want to access in your C++/CLI project.

Example:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[DllImport("YourDLLName")]
public static extern void UnmanagedMethodName(string parameter1);
```

Comment: This is not true, you can use unmanaged C++ code from C++/CLI projects without any problems, and without extra work.

Comment: Just #include the header file and link to the .lib? It is C++ after all.

Comment: Right. I was thinking about C# all the time. My bad.

Comment: @Timbo thanks for your clarification. But I have a dll file instead of lib file. Do I have to build the native C++ project for generating a lib file instead of a dll file in order to include a header file? or it is possible to include the header file with the dll file as well? I am not sure about this. do you know an example how to add the lib or dll file to a C++ managed project in visual studio? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually `C++ .Net` is a wrong term and shouldn't be used... It's C++/CLI