# Is it possible to compile C++ that's using a .NET DLL with GCC?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, gcc

I want to use the AML.Engine.dll (https://github.com/AutomationML/AMLEngine2.1) in a C++ project. I have gotten it to work with the Microsoft C++ Compiler, but also need it to work with GCC but couldn't do so yet.
Are there any compiler settings necessary to do so? Or is it just not possible with GCC?

The code below shows a simple demo project that I tried to get to work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h> 
using namespace std;
#using <AML.Engine.dll>
#using <System.dll>
#using <System.Xml.dll>
#using <System.Xml.Linq.dll>
using namespace Aml::Engine::CAEX;

int main()
{
    // create a new empty document
    auto caexDocument = CAEXDocument::LoadFromFile("BSM_Project_210219_V3.1.aml");
    CAEXDocument^ doc = CAEXDocument::New_CAEXDocument();

    for each(auto instanceHierachy in caexDocument->CAEXFile->InstanceHierarchy){
        for each(auto element in instanceHierachy->InternalElement){
            System::Console::WriteLine( element->Name) ;
            System::Console::WriteLine( "----------------------------------------------------------") ;
            for each(auto ielement in element->InternalElement){  
                System::Console::WriteLine( ielement->Name) ;
            }

        }  

    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this? As far as I know, C++ cannot use .NET binaries in this manner, it seems more likely that you are using C++/CLI which is actually C++ compiled to .NET byte code. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710581/what-is-the-main-difference-between-c-vs-c-net It therefore seems unlikely that it would be possible to do with GCC.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help. Apparently the demo code is C++/CLI, yes. But you're saying it's not possible to use the .dll in unmanaged C++ and thus make it work with GCC, right?

Comment: As far as I know - no.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 was to use a random dll in a .NET programm and vice versa.

1. it is a .NET DLL. There is nothing to do here. you can always use a .NET dll in a .NET Programm. You are already doing it just compiling any start project
2. COM interop. In many respects, .NET was a followup of the older COM approach. As a result, the .NET Framework has [extensive COM Interop support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/com-interop/introduction-to-com-interop).
3. [P/Invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/pinvoke).

Option 2 can run into binarity missmatch issues. Option 3 is almost guaranteed to.

It is not really clear if your C++ programm is C++ .NET (a case 1 scenario) or what I call native C++ (wich is any C++ except .NET). By design, .NET/MSIL are source language agnostic. It being .NET defines more about the limitations then the language does.
I can not tell if the System.Xml.Linq.dll was written in C++ .NET, C# , F# or VB .NET. And I do not need to know to use it.

Comment: Ok, so my code is C++.NET (at least as far as I know) and when compiling it with the Microsoft C++ Compiler it works fine with the DLL. Can I compile C++.NET code with GCC?

Comment: @RobinBeer As far as I can tell, GCC can not even compile to Mono. There is a dedicated compiler and IDE for that. | GCC is propably limited to compile to machine code/native C+.