# Is it possible to create a C++ console app using the `dotnet` CLI

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio-2022, dotnet-cli

I ran a `dotnew new list` command but found no templates with C++ as a language.

This [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/dotnet-programming-with-cpp-cli-visual-cpp?view=msvc-170) also mentions a CLI, but I think it might be something else in that context.

Is it possible to use the `dotnet` [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet) to create a C++ console application for Visual Studio? If not, then why not?

Comment: `but I think it might be something else in that context` - yes, it refers to [C++/CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8710661/11683) rather than a general "Command Line Interface".

Comment: @GSerg Yes, that's what I suspected, but that doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: `why not` - probably because you [couldn't build them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59730669/11683) either.

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to use the `dotnet` instead of msbuild? Generally speaking, it's easier to use things like cmake / makefiles anyway. I have a large project consisting of C++, C++/CLI, and C# all building with CMake in a nice / easy manner.

Comment: @ChrisMM because `dotnet` is not just about building, it's also about creating new projects, adding references and packages and all sorts of stuff. I would have liked to see all that power brought to C++ as well.

Comment: Are you not using Visual Studio? Which can do all that. As can CMake, fyi.

Comment: VS2010 was the last VS version that supported C++/CLI well.  Pieces have been falling off the tooling support for it ever since.  The specific lack of support you are complaining about here is for SDK-style projects, a C++/CLI project still uses the olden xml format.  Which put the kibosh on dotnet.exe project template support.  Looking at the voting in the [c++-cli] tag at SO is a good hint why Microsoft is not that interested anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++/CLI is still supported with VS2022 (both with .NET Framework, but also with .NET 6.0+), but with one significant limitation: Only libraries can be built with C++/CLI, because it's main use is to write wrapper libraries between native libraries and C# applications. Therefore, you won't find an application template (neither command line nor windowed) any more, because C++/CLI projects can't be applications. You always need a C# (or VB, if you want) project as startup project.

Two "Empty CLR project" templates exist for creating a C++/CLI project, for .NET framework and .NET respectively.

Comment: The project template is named "CLR Console App (.NET Framework)"

Comment: @PMF Sorry but upon further review I find too many issues with this answer to consider it sufficiently viable. Firstly, the assertion that no windowed application templates are available is incorrect. Filtering for C++ in the Visual Studio "New Project" dialog reveals several C++ templates such as "Console App", "Windows Desktop Application" and "CLR Console app". Secondly, I believe you have conflated the C++/CLI with the `dotnet` CLI, with which you can build several types of libraries using `dotnet new` including C#, F#, VB and Powershell libraries, so why not for C++?

Comment: @user32882 Ok, I might have missed a few points here. Fact is: `dotnet` is the entry point for the .NET (C#/Vb) compiler and runtime. It cannot build C++ projects, and therefore it would be kind of strange if it supported creating them. Visual Studio, on the other hand, also supports the C++ compiler, and therefore can create projects for it. Visual Studio uses `msbuild` as the build engine. `msbuild` supports compiling C# apps and libs (and C++), but not the other way round.

Comment: Then, and that was the main point in my answer, there's a "combined" project type, called a C++/CLI project, which is a C++ project, but built for the .NET runtime (instead of the native windows API). Such a project can only be built using the C++ compiler, but it can run using dotnet.

Comment: When you say that a C++/CLI project can be built using the C++ compiler, you really mean `msbuild` right? So `msbuild` will run a `cl` command (using MSVC) but `dotnet` cannot do that apparently. I guess that's what you mean?

Comment: @user32882 Yes, that's what I mean.